# how to find real file from link

Tags: symbolic-link

```
ls -l java
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 2019-02-17 11:37 java -> /etc/anotherLink/java
```

when I do ls -l it shows path to file, but that file can also be a link. is there any way to show path to real file?

Answer (score 11):

I think what you want is `readlink`:

```
readlink -f java
```

To find this, I asked which manual page might by appropriate for symbolic links.

```
apropos "symbolic link"
```

It returned a reference to readlink, so I used the manual:

```
man readlink
```

I read the manual page:

> -f, --canonicalize
>         canonicalize by following every symlink in every component of the given name recursively; all but the last component must exist

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Try using `file` command.

It shows details about a given file (type, contents format)

Example:

```
$ cp -s temp.sh temp2.sh
$ file temp2.sh 
temp2.sh: symbolic link to `temp.sh'
```

Comment: I think the question is about one more level of links, e.g. `one` (link) -> `two` (link) -> `three` (regular file) and a command to show `one` points to `three`. `file one` will show `one: symbolic link to 'two'` whereas `readlink -f one` will show `/abs/path/to/three`.